# Sql Server Reporting Services stops working after changing service Logon account

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, team-foundation-server, service-accounts

Using Sql Server 2008.

I am attempting to install Team Foundation Server as a dual server setup (due to one server being the DC.) Part of the installation requirements is that Sql Server Reporting Services (SSRS) can not use the local system account to run which it defaults to.

I've been following the installation procedures included along the account generation that is needed for team foundation server. I setup a domain account "TFSReports" and granted it the log on locally rights as per the account requirements guide lines.

However anytime I stop SSRS and change the account to use TFSReports or even using NTAuthority\NetworkService (the other acceptable account to use per guidelines) after starting the service it just seems as though Reporting Services just doesn't work anymore.

I can't even browse to LocalHost/Reports when I change the account. If I go back to the service and flip it back to use local system account and restart the service I can view LocalHost/Reports again fine.

Edit: This is the exact message I'm getting from the TFS install and following the instructions seems to stop SSRS from working afterwards.

Description
SQL Server Reporting Services is configured to use Local System as the service account.

Workaround / Remedy
You must use either the Network Service system account or a valid domain account for the SQL Server Reporting Services service account. In Control Panel, double-click Administrative Tools, double-click Services, and then look for the SQL Server Reporting Services service. Double-click the service to view the service properties. Select the Log On tab. In Log On As, click This account, change the account information, and then click OK.

Do I need to follow these instructions **AND** make changes to the SQL Server Configuration Manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we're talking SQL Server 2005, the SQL Server Reporting Service is a scheduling engine. It does not determine the web application side. So changing the service account there shouldn't have an effect on the web app. With that said, how are you changing the service account? It should be done using Reporting Services configuration and SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Comment: Added information to the question.

Comment: To what you added... Microsoft generally recommends the use of the configuration tools. That ensures file and registry permissions are set properly, too. I would use them and not Services.

Comment: Thank you, using the configuration application allowed me to change the username to my domain account I created for it and actually have SSRS continue working afterward! I've never had a worse time trying to install Microsoft Software than installing TFS.